# Attempting to use Social.framework on ios 5.1.1 crashes my App

Tags: ios, frameworks, crash

My app is getting an error message and crashes on the iOS 5.1 simulator because this iOS 5.1.1 doesn't support the "Social" framework.

Is there a way to solve this and use it on versions prior to iOS 6?

Answer (score 7):

The Social Framework is an iOS 6 Only feature. It will NOT work on devices running iOS earlier than 6.0. You have two options. If your App is new you can require iOS 6 or greater.

If your App has been out there for a while and you need to support versions of iOS earlier than 6 you can test for the existence of the framework at run time with something like this:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil) {
    // The social Framework exists
else
    // Social Framework does NOT exist.
```

NOTE IN RESPONSE TO YOUR COMMENT BELOW:
It is considered bad design to use the version number to check for the existence of a feature. The recommended approach is to check for the existence of the feature itself.

The code you mentioned in the comment is a perfect example of WHY you test for the feature and not the version. The floatValue of  @"5.1.1" is 5.1 AND the floatValue of @"5.1.2" is also 5.1! If the feature your looking for is not in 5.1.1 but IS in 5.1.2 your code will NOT detect it and incorrectly assume the feature DOES NOT exist. Don't do this. Use the technique I outlined above.

Comment: You should also mark the framework as optional under your Project>Target>Summary Tab> Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Comment: I tried different thing: float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
        if (version>=6)
        { //code }

Comment: Do not do that... it can break as you wrote it. See my comment above in my Answer....

Comment: Just making sure nobody misses MaxGabriel's comment either - if you target anything below iOS6 you'll need to mark the linked Social framework as optional.